# Software download issues in general

Tags: download-manager

Hi this is described as an open source cross platform suite that is an ideal starting place for developing software to be used for Chemistry & Molecular modelling. Seems like fun however the download link from their website (http://openbabel.org/) directs to a source forge page [as linked here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/openbabel/files/openbabel/2.4.1/OpenBabel-2.4.1.exe/download), and I have tried all of the other mirrors suggested if I encounter download problems and unfortunately encountered the same result.

Is there a type of software that can assess whether or not a download issue has causality at the server end or my end i.e my network settings are causing the problem?

Comment: Did you try downloading from a different PC? On a different network?

Comment: Well I only have one network but ok yeah I guess I could try with a tor service running on one of my Linux systems but aside from that I don't know how to make a new network with only the one internet connection

Comment: Just trying to vary some things, to see what can be discovered. Maybe a friend or relative's PC? Or a  software downloader app? Orr FTP instead of HTTP, if available

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention the OS you need the tool for. You can `ping` the actual download server, from windows cmd.exe:

`ping -n 5 download.server.name.com`

This will give you response times for the ping in milliseconds. `-n 5` means ping the server only 5 times, otherwise ping runs forever. It might help.

You can also use `tracert` on Windows:

`tracert duckduckgo.com`

It will look at the response time for every server between you and the target `duckduckgo.com`. This will help you find a possible bottleneck.